# MS SQL CONTAINS with Ampersand Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have a FULLTEXT column called 'name', which may contain multiple words per row.  Using CONTAINS, I can search for a variable number of words, and it works, except when one of the words has an ampersand in it.

Example: name = 'Bob Brown AB&CD'
This works:

```
CONTAINS(name, '"*Bo*" AND "*Br*"')
```

These do not (any search of the word with the ampersand):

```
CONTAINS(name, '"*AB*"')
CONTAINS(name,'"*AB&CD*"')
CONTAINS(name,'"*&*"')
```

I realize why the last search wouldn't work, since CONTAINS only searches from the beginning of words.

Is the ampersand being processed by FULLTEXT as a word-break?  If so, that might explain why a search including the ampersand would fail.  But it wouldn't explain why

```
CONTAINS(name, '"*AB*"')
CONTAINS(name, '"*CD*"') (assuming FULLTEXT sees "CD" as a different word)
```

would fail.

How can I mitigate the search so it returns the row if I search for "AB&CD" or just "AB" or just "CD"?

P.S.  Dynamic SQL is not an option, so I cannot concatenate a variable number of LIKEs.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, apparently.  I set

```
STOPLIST = OFF
```

on my FULLTEXT index, and I can now search by "*AB*" and "*AB&CD*" successfully.